# Reading assets or raw or resource files as a File object in Android

Tags: android, file-handling, android-resources

I have a jar file for which i need to pass file object. How can i pass resource or assets to that method as a file object?

How to convert assets or raw files in the project folders in to file objects ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what I did:

Copy Your asset file into SDCard:

```
AssetManager assetManager = context.getResources().getAssets();

String[] files = null;

try {
    files = assetManager.list("ringtone"); //ringtone is folder name
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ERROR: " + e.toString());
}

for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        in = assetManager.open("ringtone/" + files[i]);
        out = new FileOutputStream(basepath + "/ringtone/" + files[i]);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[65536 * 2];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
        in.close();
        in = null;
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Ringtone File Copied in SD Card");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "ERROR: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Then read your file by the path:

```
File ringFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/ringtone", "fileName.mp3");
```

There you go. You have a copy of file object of your asset file. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am getting Out of Memory in my application if i did like this.

Comment: This is working for me. I omitted some part. Please create the folder using mkdirs() method of file object before this code. You can google it.

Comment: You are getting out of memory exception for @vipul's and my solutions... can you paste the logcat entries. something is not right. you testing on device or emulator?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to get an actual `File` object, but if you can work with a `FileDescriptor`, you could do:

```
FileDescriptor fd = getAssets().openFd(assetFileName).getFileDescriptor();
```

Comment: I don't know in what way this can be used. Can you explain the usage of this descriptor.