# Loading files from raw folder in Android

Tags: android

Suppose I store various images in raw folder. However, my own code first learns of the file names at runtime. (It reads a text configuration file at startup.) Is it possible to then search "raw" folder in my android app and if found, load image from raw into imageview?

Comment: Why don't you just put your images in drawable folder and load it from there?

Comment: Well if you said asset directory, I would probably understand your end game, but like this, this is no different from putting your images in drawable folder, maybe you were looking to open your image just knowing its name, then look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349652/android-open-resource-from-drawable-string. And just in case you can find your image like this `R.raw.yourimage`

Comment: @Mario: Are you loading your images using "R.raw.yourimage" because that is what I need to do, i.e. with "". (I want to store text files, images etc. custom for each client, i.e. skinning. I am replacing the folder before compiling with clients images, config files reading during start etc.)

Comment: @Mario That said, I guess I will be using res/raw for storing my configuration files, and then assets for images for which I can't use the "R.xxx" resource constants for. (Still new to Android, so the difference was not immediately apparent to me)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, thanks to Mario I got on track to doing some research. These 5 SO's explain everything:

- [Android images in /assets or res/raw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423460/android-images-in-assets-or-res-raw)
- [Reading assets or raw or resource files as a File object in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10930716/reading-assets-or-raw-or-resource-files-as-a-file-object-in-android)
- [How to reference a File in raw folder in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9752417/how-to-reference-a-file-in-raw-folder-in-android)
- [Check for file existence in androids assets folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592836/check-for-file-existence-in-androids-assets-folder)
- [Difference between /res and /assets directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583608/difference-between-res-and-assets-directories)